# PowerBi DAX measure to sum duration of timespans filtered by current slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, timespan

I need a DAX measure that gives me the sum of durations for multiple categories restricted by a date slicer.

In this simplified example there are 2 categories with 3 subcategories each. A DateTime Slicer on the dashboard is set to the timespan of 2nd of January 2021 noon to 6th of January midnight. I need the summed up duration of all categories in this timespan.

[image: Overview of Data]

Input data:
A table containing multiple rows for each category with a start date and an end date.
[image: Input Data]

The complicated part is that there are pauses between the timestamps.

Desired output:
A table on the dashboard containing the category and a calculated measure for the summed up duration during the sliced timespan.

[image: Desired output]

When changing the slicer the meaure shall change as well.

My current solution for this problem is an M formulato create a list of all days in each timespan and to unpivot all lists. In the dashboard the count of rows gives you the number of days in the selected timespan. This solution though reqires a much larger input table and soes not work if you want to be exact on the second, only on days.

I tried so solve this via a measure but didn't make any progress worth showing here.

*all datetime values are in the format dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss (24h system)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it by using 2 measures.
First measure calculates the time during the timespan for each element:
I use one Date Table only consisting of all dates available which is the input for the slicer and the data Table called "Data".

```
duration_in_timespan_single = 
VAR MinTs = MIN ('Date'[Date])
VAR MaxTs = MAX ('Date'[Date])
VAR MinUtcMin = MIN ('Data'[Date_Start])
VAR MaxUtcMax = MAX ('Data'[Date_End])

RETURN 
IF(
    AND(MinUtcMin >= MinTs, MinUtcMin <= MaxTs),
    IF(
        MaxUtcMax <= MaxTs,
        CONVERT((MaxUtcMax-MinUtcMin),DOUBLE),
        CONVERT((MaxTs-MinUtcMin),DOUBLE)),
    IF(
        MinUtcMin < MinTs,
        IF(
            MaxUtcMax > MinTs,
            IF(
                MaxUtcMax <= MaxTs,
                CONVERT((MaxUtcMax-MinTs),DOUBLE),
                CONVERT((MaxTs-MinTs),DOUBLE)
            ),
           0
        ),
        0
    )
)
```

The second measure just sums up the first for each category:

```
duration_in_timespan = SUMX('Data',[duration_in_timespan_single])
```